# Can not find indexpath in scope in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, indexpath

```
import UIKit

private let reuseableIdentifier = "cell"

class TableViewController: UITableViewController{
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         
      tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseableIdentifier)
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseableIdentifier, for: indexPath ) 
        return cell
    }

    
}
```

So this is my code but at the dequereuseableCell for: indexPath it showing error like can not find indexPath in scope.

Comment: You've implemented incorrect data source method for cell.

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection is an correct method for dataSource

Comment: But you need to return an Int not a cell from it. You’ve implemented cellForRowAtIndexPath in numberOfRowsInSection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to return a number greater than 0 in the method of `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`
2. You need to return a cell in the method of `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```swift
import UIKit

private let reuseableIdentifier = "cell"

class TableViewController: UITableViewController{
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         
      tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseableIdentifier)
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // return number of rows in sections
        return 10
    }
    
    // add method
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseableIdentifier, for: indexPath )
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i got it i just did silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are still missing one method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     // dequeue your cell here
}
```

the method you use should read:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return the number of elements to show here
}
```

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller)

[tutorial](https://www.ralfebert.com/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/)

Comment: yes i got it i just did silly mistake